# Store data that implements a trait in a vector

Tags: pointers, vector, rust, traits, lifetime

I'm very new to Rust and system languages in general. And I'm currently playing around with Rust to explore the language. I've a problem that I cannot fix by myself. And I think I've understanding problem whats going on.

I wan't to store objects that implements the `trait BaseStuff` in a vector. In Rust not a simple task for me :-).

Here is my example code that won't compile.

```
trait BaseStuff {}

struct MyStuff {
    value: i32,
}

struct AwesomeStuff {
    value: f32,
    text: String,
}

impl BaseStuff for MyStuff {}

impl BaseStuff for AwesomeStuff {}

struct Holder {
    stuff: Vec<BaseStuff>,
}

impl Holder {
    fn register(&mut self, data: impl BaseStuff) {
        self.stuff.push(data);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_stuff = MyStuff { value: 100 };

    let awesome_stuff = AwesomeStuff {
        value: 100.0,
        text: String::from("I'm so awesome!"),
    };

    let mut holder = Holder { stuff: vec![] };

    holder.register(my_stuff);
}
```

> error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn BaseStuff + 'static)`
>   cannot be known at compilation time   --> src\main.rs:17:5    | 17 |
>   stuff: Vec, // unknown size    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   doesn't have a size known at compile-time    |    = help: the trait
>   `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn BaseStuff +
>   'static)`    = note: to learn more, visit
>   https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait
>   = note: required by `std::vec::Vec`
>
> error: aborting due to previous error
>
> For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
>   error: Could not compile `playground`.
>
> The compiler message is clear and I understand the message. I can
>   implement the trait BaseStuff in any struct I want't so its unclear
>   which size it is. Btw the link isn't helpful because its pointing to
>   outdated site...

The size of String is also unknown, but the String implements the trait `std::marker::Sized` and that's why a `Vec<String>` will work without problems. Is that correct?

In the rust book I read for data types with unknown size I've to store these data on the heap instead of the stack. I changed my code as follows.

```
struct Holder {
    stuff: Vec<Box<BaseStuff>>,
}

impl Holder {
    fn register(&mut self, data: impl BaseStuff) {
        self.stuff.push(Box::new(data));
    }
}
```

Now I'm hitting a new compiler issue:

> error[E0310]: the parameter type `impl BaseStuff` may not live long
>   enough   --> src\main.rs:22:25    | 21 |     fn register(&mut self,
>   data: impl BaseStuff) {    |
>   --------------- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `impl BaseStuff: 'static`... 22 |         self.stuff.push(Box::new(data));
>   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    | note: ...so that the
>   type `impl BaseStuff` will meet its required lifetime bounds   -->
>   src\main.rs:22:25    | 22 |         self.stuff.push(Box::new(data));
>   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> error: aborting due to previous error
>
> For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0310`.
>   error: Could not compile `playground`.

And know I'm out... I read in the book about lifetimes and changed my code a lot with `'a` here and `'a` in any combination but without luck... I don't want to write down any lifetime definition combination I tried.
I don't understand why I need the lifetime definition. The ownership is moved in any step so for my understanding its clear that Holder struct is the owner for all data. Is it?

How can I correct my code to compile?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Without static lifetime you can solve this issue by just expecting boxed BaseStuff : `fn register(&mut self, data: Box<BaseStuff> )` , please check the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7d6ee9c38004e9a5eb07e3c39076d288).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *almost* got it - the issue here is that the type for which `BaseStuff` is implemented may be a reference (e.g. `impl BaseStuff for &SomeType`). This means that even though you're passing `data` by value, the value may be a reference that will be outlived by your `Box`.

The way to fix this is to add a constraint such that the object has a `'static` lifetime, meaning it will either be a value type or a static reference. You can apply this constraint to the trait or the method accepting the trait, depending on your use case.

Applying the constraint to the trait:

```rust
trait BaseStuff: 'static {}
```

Applying the constraint to the method:

```rust
impl Holder {
    fn register(&mut self, data: impl BaseStuff + 'static) {
        self.stuff.push(Box::new(data));
    }
}
```

If you add the `'static` constraint to the method, I would recommend also adding it to the `Vec` to avoid losing type information, like so:

```rust
struct Holder {
    stuff: Vec<Box<dyn BaseStuff + 'static>>,
}
```

Comment: Simply  this would also work : `data: impl BaseStuff + 'static `. But the question is why vec.push requires static lifetime. `data` must have already moved ?

Comment: @ÖmerErden the static lifetime is required because the data being added to the vector may itself be a reference. `BaseStuff` can be implemented for any type - for example, `impl BaseStuff for &SomeType` would allow you to pass a reference like `&SomeType` to the method. This then triggers the lifetime checks, because the reference itself is being stored in the box, not the value the reference referes to.

Comment: Oh i should have check the explanation first,  thanks. But i would prefer sending boxed data to holder

Comment: But what will happen if i would Box a reference of a type then send it to the push ?

Comment: @ÖmerErden could you show me an example of what you mean? Boxing a reference (`Box<&SomeType>`) seems like a weird use case, but it should work if the reference has a `'static` lifetime, and fail otherwise.

Comment: Yes it's a weird use case, you can box it without static lifetime but you cannot send the box inside to a register fn, please check the last line in main() - [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=555d9e38008bef8ec831bbddcb9587fb)

Comment: @ÖmerErden In that case you can create a named lifetime to ensure that all references live at least as long as the struct itself - [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2f0ed81fb697b2dc2a52ae35ec19e6bc)

Comment: Yes, adding lifetime will solve the issue, actually i was wondering if we can trick the compiler by sending the boxed reference , looks like it is not possible, anyway thanks .)